# Non fat bakimg milk powder vs regular

Tags: milk, powder

I recently bought milk powder for baking which is non fat,
Can I use it to make non fat milk or other non baking uses?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

Yes, powdered milk can be reconstituted to make liquid milk by adding it to cold water.  (Usually there are directions for proportions on the package.)  The flavor won't be quite like fresh milk, but if well-chilled and allowed to rest and completely dissolve, it can create liquid milk that's useful for drinking and other standard uses.

Aside from using the liquid milk in standard ways, powdered milk can also be used in a variety of recipes, creating everything from substitutes for evaporated milk (by using less water) and condensed milk (less water and adding sugar) to separate uses for milk powder, like "coffee creamer" or adding to other ingredients to create drink mixes.  Some even use a concentrated liquid version to create a kind of whipped topping or dip, and I've even seen uses for reconstituted milk powder to make yogurt, cheese, etc.

In general, in my somewhat limited experiments, I haven't found most of the latter applications to result in a good flavored product, so I mostly have used dry milk powder only when adding it to dry ingredients in some other recipe.  But in a pinch, it can be used for just about anything normal liquid milk can be used for and more.

Comment: A couple of very useful applications I've found: porridge (oatmeal)  for camping or eating in work, that only needs boiling water to make, and hot chocolate (creamier than bought instant)